# How to not display specific UILabels for unique entries in a Master-Detail app

Tags: swift, core-data, master-detail

I have an core-data application that is using the standard Master-Detail style.

Some objects/items in core-data don't have all fields populated.  The question is:

How can I not display the UILabels for a given field, if that entry doesn't have the data?  If I tell it to check / not display, it seems to check all entries, not just the one on the detail view.

```
        if let label_pet1PetInfoLicense = self.pet1PetInfoLicense {
            label_pet1PetInfoLicense.text = detail.valueForKey("pet_info_dog_license_number")!.description

            pet1PetInfoLicense.hidden = false
            pet1PetInfoLicenseROW.hidden = false
        } else {
            self.pet1PetInfoLicense?.hidden = true
            self.pet1PetInfoLicenseROW?.hidden = true
        }
```

In the above example, since at least one of my pets contains a pet license information, the two UILabels are being displayed for all pets.

If I only include two pets, neither of which have a dog license info recorded, then neither of the details-pages will show the two UILabels.

I'd like the display to be unique to the data for each core-data object.

Thoughts?

Comment: Do I need to reference the individual core data element that the DetailViewController is working on?

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Figuring that the Detail View of a Master-Detail app should be allowed to be different based on the content...

Comment: +signal boost #trying not to be annoying...